# SQL - Dates equal from two columns

Tags: sql

I have this query and would like to see the dates only where effective_date from one table = renewal_date from the other table.

```
SELECT 
    facets_re_group.prospect_nbr, rmr_run_status, insert_date, renewal_date,  
    package_item_cd, quote_type, effective_date, quote_expiration_ind,   
    mhs_lob_code
FROM 
    facets_re_group
INNER JOIN 
    facets_re_cur_package ON facets_re_cur_package.prospect_nbr = facets_re_group.prospect_nbr 
JOIN 
    qo_quote ON qo_quote.prospect_nbr = facets_re_group.prospect_nbr
WHERE 
    insert_date >= to_date('01/01/2020','mm/dd/yyyy') 
    AND package_item_cd = 'HRA' 
    AND quote_expiration_ind IS NULL 
    AND mhs_lob_code NOT IN 'DTL1' 
    AND mhs_lob_code NOT IN 'DTL2' 
    AND mhs_lob_code NOT IN 'VIS1'
```

Comment: So update the `where` clause or the join clause to reflect that.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)